# How do i append or prepend this dynamic rows in to the table using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

$j=1;
            ?>
        
            var t ='';
            var options = "";

```
    </script>   
        <?php 
        foreach ($this->data['DEFAULTS'] as $rec){
            foreach ($rec as $key=>$val){
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var cntr = "<?php echo $j;?>";
        var reference_value = '<?php echo $val["GETVAL"];?>';
        var sel = '<select name="code[]">'+options+'</select>';
        var txt  = '<input type="text" class="TextBox" name="referencevalue[]"  valign="top" value="'+ reference_value +'">';                  
            t += '<tr id ='+cntr+'><td>'+cntr+'</td><td valign="top">'+sel+'</td><td valign="top" ailgn="center">'+txt+'</td></tr>';                        
            </script>

        <?php
        $j++;               
                }
            }
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        alert("MYTABLE "+t);
        $("#ref").append(t);
        </script>

       when i say alert(t) iam getting the entire table structure  and the data  but iam not able to add it  to the table 
   .Here is the Table Structure where i have to add 
                <table width="100%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" align="left">
                <tbody><tr>
                <th class="coltextleft">
                <span style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold;" id="id_refTbl">
                <img id="IMG1" height="15" width="15" align="middle" src="cllpsed.gif"/> </span>
                </th>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>
                <div id="ref" style="display:none">
                <table id="ref" width="100%" class="formTable">
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>  Code</td>
                    <td> Value</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>I need to add  the result of alert(t) with inthis rows</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*First, kind of meta to the question:* why are you doing this?  Why not just render the markup directly in the page via PHP instead of rendering `<script>` elements for the client to accomplish the same task?

---

*To directly answer:*  Your code needs to be wrapped in a `document.ready` handler, since the element with `id="ref"` isn't yet in the DOM when you're executing:

```
$("#ref").append(t);
```

So it isn't finding the element...that doesn't exist yet.  Wrap it in a `ready` handler, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#ref").append(t);
});
```

This way it executed after the DOM is completely loaded/ready to go, and the `#ref` selector *will* find the `<table>` you're after.

---

To make this work though, you'll also need to remove the `id` from `<div id="ref" style="display:none">`, since IDs need to be unique.

Comment: Thanks It worked out .So my Problem is .How do i get the option selected  that is returned from my php function 
var my_option_selected  = "<?php echo json_encode(StuClass::getopt($val["CDE"],$opt));?>";
var sel = '<select name="code[] selected =????">'+options+'</select>';

Comment: @Someone - that needs to go in your `<option>` element as an attribute as `<option selected>` - for the one that should be selected, add the `selected` attribute :)

Comment: I have two rows already for the table "ref" i have to add the dynamic rows after the two rows

Comment: I got It Nick Thanks for your Help $("#ref tr:first")

Answer (score 1):

If the variable t is the whole table markup, then yeah, that might not work if you are trying to append it to the table.  You'd probably want t to be:

```
var t = '<tr><td>foo</td></tr>'
```

At that point, you should be able to:

```
$("table#ref").append(t)
```

jQuery#append adds the markup to the end of the target element's children.

Comment: `.prepend()` works as well, it inserts the elements as the first child rather than the last.  Also his `t` is *just* rows.  Last, *never* use a `anything#id` selector if you can avoid it, it's *much* slower.

Comment: Good point on the selector advice -- I thought that using an element name based selector was still very fast because it's based by native DOM query methods.  You do definitely want to avoid className based queries though if possible, or at least to narrow the scope of the search.

Comment: It depends, since jQuery 1.4.3 most things are using `querySelectorAll()` if available, but `#id` is a special case that doesn't even go to Sizzle, it's a direct `document.getElementById("id")` shortcut, so it's *much* faster than *any* other selector :)